# jira hsql database have been corrupted

Tags: jira, hsqldb, jira-agile

my hsql database of JIRA has been corrupted due to power-jerk, we have been trying to recover this Hsql database but we haven't found any proper solution yet.is there any way to recover this database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use HSQLDB for a production environment? Because this is absolutely not recommended:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+JIRA+to+HSQLDB

If you have the XML Backup service enabled, it might have saved some of your data in JIRA_HOME/exports

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Automating+JIRA+Backups